# liboobs size mismatch when upgrading to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, package-management

I get this error when trying to upgrade to 11.04:

```
Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libo/liboobs/liboobs-1-5_2.32.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Size mismatch
```

I already did a bunch of *apt-get clean; apt-get update;* in different days and it continues to have this problem.

I know that this probably means one of these three things:

- The repository's deb is broken and mismatches the checksum I have in cache.
- My cache's deb is broken and mismatches the checksum I have in cache.
- My cache's checksum is broken and mismatches the deb in the repository

How should I try to solve this problem?

Comment: please don't roll back this revision - this is a title people might actually type into Google. Thanks.

Comment: I will lock this question if you continue to insist on putting `Boobs` in the title. You have been warned.

Comment: It is almost certain that the download fails because a firewall or proxy spots the string "boobs" in the file name and substitutes a Web page for the download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for the problem mentioned above was to download the alternate cd, mount it, and upgrade from it, as described in the upgrade-related documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you could download that and install it using dpkg

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libo/liboobs/liboobs-1-5_2.32.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -f liboobs-1-5_2.32.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: no I cannot. I am upgrading the system. and that -f looks really dangerous when being done in a package with size mismatch!